# Calling a function that takes a callback as argument using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

How can I call the following `sum()` function with Rhino (`org.mozilla.javascript`, not `javax.script`), passing it a Java method as a callback (or any other way that would allow me to receive the result back in Java), once I have the Rhino `Function` object representing it?

```
function sum(a, b, successHandler) {
    successHandler(a + b);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should `return successHandler(a+b);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
function.call(context, scope, null, new org.mozilla.javascript.Function() {
    @Override
    public Object call(Context cx, Scriptable scope, Scriptable thisObj, Object[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    },

    // ...
});
```

It's unfortunate that `org.mozilla.javascript.Function` is such a large interface, but everything seems to work correctly, even if none of the required methods have a real implementation.

This is not exactly elegant though. I wish there was a better way.

Comment: can you please explain the exact implementation of this.. i hav a javascript function and after executing the function want to make a call to java. please suggest... searching for this since last two weeks.. thanks